# SVG text (tspan) with hebrew text - words break to other words's location

Tags: svg

I want to break svg text to multiple lines, so I added tspan objects for each line in the text.
With english words it works well, but with hebrew words all the words split and mix together.
I know that I can split every line to seperate text element,
But I need all the text in one text element (for programattically workflow).

This is my code:

```html
<svg class="concepta_preview_option_2 concepta_preview" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
            <text fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="50px" data-font_size="50" data-max_width="1512" x="100" y="100" visibility="visible" id="concepta_field_2_copy_preview" >
                <tspan x="100" dy="-50px" fill="transparent" text-anchor="middle">------</tspan>
                <tspan x="100" dy="0px" text-anchor="middle">אאאאא</tspan>
                <tspan x="100" dy="50px" text-anchor="middle">בבבב</tspan>
                <tspan x="100" dy="100px" text-anchor="middle">גגגגגגגגגגג</tspan>
                <tspan x="100" dy="150px" text-anchor="middle">דד</tspan>
                <tspan x="100" dy="200px" fill="transparent" text-anchor="middle">------</tspan>
            </text>
        </svg>
```

This is the problematic result:

[image]

Comment: Seems fine to me in Firefox. If you've a bug in another browser, report it to that browser's bugtracker.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245618 and several others that seem to be related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=433217, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=rtl%20tspan%20component%3ABlink%3ESVG&can=2